# Restrict bandwidth usage in cloud game server

Tags: video, streaming, bandwidth, x264

I am working on cloud game server development.

During the testing of some games, there is a spike observed of around 10 MBps. Normally game consumes 4~6 MBps network bandwidth.

Is there any way to keep consumed bandwidth <5 MBps without much affecting video quality?

720p resolution is being used. We are using x264 encoder, are there any params of this encoder which may help me out to achieve expected o/p ?